# UITextField.becomeFirstResponder() does not work properly

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift2

I'm writing a to do list app, and when I click a `UIButton` to add a new task, I want a new `TableViewCell` to pop up, that contains a `UITextField`. However, when I set this `UITextfiel`d to first responder, with the following code:

```
let cellIdentifier = "TaskTableViewCell"
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: newIndexPath) as! TaskTableViewCell
cell.nameLabel.becomeFirstResponder()
```

However when I do this, a keyboard pops up but a cursor does not, and when I type, I can see autocorrect options, but no characters ever appear in the `textfield`.

Wondering what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Check if there is any view/label overlapping your textfield in cell.

Comment: @kenny try changing with text color & tint color.

Comment: Check whether u have added textfield delegate to view controller .

Comment: are you doing this on cellForRowAtIndexPath method??

Comment: My understanding is that you cannot set a firstResponder inside cellForRowAtIndexPath as it is called on a background thread. UI related items shall be set on the main thread. Try to set the firstResponder inside willDisplayCell instead.

Comment: I should have clarified, I'm currently using a @IBAction func that when i click on add, it adds a new cell and also sets cell.nameLabel.becomeFirstResponder()

Comment: Doesn't seem like theres' any overlap because I can tap on the field normally and edit normally, but it just seems I can't with becomeFirstResponder, and I have added the textfield delegate

Comment: still nothing? Would really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You should create `IBOutlet` for textField and `IBAction` for button. And it should look like this:

```
class TaskTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{ 
   @IBAction func buttonPressed()
   {
      self.myTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
   }
}
```

Comment: That's currently what I'm doing